# Android-Java List to String and vice versa

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming and I wanted to create a function to take in a list and return a String. That's my code:

```
private String List_to_String(final ArrayList<String> list) {
String returnString = "{";
for (String _s : list) {

returnString = returnString + _s.replace(":","\\:") + ":";

}

if (returnString != null && returnString.length() > 0) {
returnString = returnString.substring(0, 
returnString.length() - 1);
}

returnString = returnString.concat("}");

return returnString;
}
```

It works but now I want to make a function that returns a ArrayList when I give a String generated with the function above also I think you need to take extra care of the ":".
So if I have a String

```
HDJDJJDJ:JSJSJSJJSJS:SJJSHS\:\:JS
```

the function should return a list with these items

```
HDJDJJDJ
JSJSJSJJSJS
SJJSHS::JS
```

Can you understand me
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this.

In Android Studio 
[File]->[Project Structure]->[Dependencies]->[Add Dependency]->[Library Dependency]-> choose 'app'(If you have multiple modules) -> search for 'GSON' -> choose implementation.

Initialize Gson in java class :

```
Private Gson gson = new Gson();
```

String to List :

```
List<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>();
String myString = gson.toJson(myList);
```

List to string :

```
Type myType = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
myList = gson.fromJson(myString, myType);
```

Comment: Thanks thought Json doesn't work for ArrayList<String>